# Exact Quran font with Thajweed - ios

Tags: ios, fonts, arabic, arabic-support

I have an ios Quran app project, i have tested several `Arabic` fonts for my Quran app text contents, but it has some difference (in Tajweed marks) other than the original Quran text with Tajweed marks. (Please check the images). I want to know which font is the correct one for Quranic text with complete Tajweed marks.

> **Edit**: I have tried so many fonts like; al-quranalkareem.ttf,UthmanicHafs.ttf,etc. (I don't think it'll be useful if I am listing all here). I want the Quran font with complete and exact Tajweed marks.

**It show like this in my app**

[image: It show like this in my app]

**It should be like this (As it is the correct one)**
[image: It should be like this (As it is the correct one)]

*Note for those who don't know Arabic: It is not two different font styles. Its Tajweed rule shows different.*

Comment: Cutting your images in half would make it much more readable also.

Comment: @Michal : it is png that why, solved now

Comment: Do you know the name of the previous font?

Comment: i have used so many, at last   al-quranalkareem.ttf

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your problem is not only about font. You are using a text that contains not all Tajweed symbols. You can download a full Uthmani script for Quran from here: [Tanzil](http://tanzil.net/download/).

For fonts, I suggest using `me_quran`,`Scheherazade`, `KacstQurn`, or `KFGQPC Uthman Taha Naskh`. See a preview of each one [here](http://sneetsher.alwaysdata.net/a/t/alfanous_fonts_test/).

[Scheherazade](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=scheherazade) font is working well for me:

[image: Uthmani Script]

See the same font for a text that is in standard script with no Tajweed symbols:
[image: Standard]

Comment: How did you colored them with tajweed rules can you share code ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan www.alfanous.org

Comment: I mean do you have ios code that colors the string text to attributed before you assign to label , i already have the quran database i just need the swift script that does the coloring by rules according to the supplied string text ?

Answer (score 4):

go to the original source of this font which is King Fahad Quran Complex as they have developed the font and explained it http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/